# Python - working with unkown directory name versions

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using python to download an application from a content distribution network. The application downloads as self extract file cabinet. When executed it creates a directory using a version naming format. For example `app-version2/../app.exe`, Thus I cannot rely on the folder name as it may change in the future. I'm trying to find the best way to work with the content inside the folder without depending on the actual folder name.

My idea was to rename the folder using `os.listdir()` and then `os.rename(app-version2, myapp)` This would work but is not automated. What would be the best automated method to find a folder name that contains version numbers and change that to something more static?

Comment: You can find all files or folders in a directory and parse their names, you can also select the ones that finish a certain way.is that what you're looking for?

Comment: You might wanna look into ``glob`` and ``re``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to find the path of the directory which begins with `app`, you can accomplish this using [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
from pathlib import Path

app_path = next(Path().glob('app*'))
```

This will give you the path to the first file or directory in your current directory whose name begins with "app".